# При условии If заставить Py Telegram bot генерировать число

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

При условии If заставить Telegram bot на Python 
Генерировать число которое будет направленно в сообщение к заказчику и это же число отправить мне на почту.

```
if text == 'генерируй число ':
```

Тут бот должен совершить вышесказанные действия.

Comment: Так а где код? В чем вопрос?

Comment: Исправляюсь. Спасибо

Comment: Это не стол заказов, мы помогает решать ошибки и возникшие вопросы, но никак не выполнять ваш заказ.

Comment: Это не заказ, я просто попросил поделиться. К чему этот негатив? Кому-то это может быть полезно. Стол заказов это тз + многоуровневые задания.

Comment: random для генерации

Comment: покажите свой скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль random

```
if text == "генерируй число":

    import random

    number = random.randint(минимальное_число, максимальное_число)
```

Осталось только вывести текст. Можно также сделать import в самом начале кода, а можно использовать

```
from random import randint

number = randint(минимальное_число, макимальное_число)
```